# Pls advise JQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, methods

There are 8 div elements. When a user clicks on one certain element some actions suppose to occur (other elements should disappear, get blurred, transparent, or whatever). I want everything to get back to the initial state (all the elements are displayed, not blurred or transparent) right after the user clicks again (or taps on the mobile screen) anywhere, on any screen area. So, I tried the following:

```
$(".element-1").mousedown(function(){
// actions...
});

$("body").click(function(){
// actions...
});
```

But this doesn't work normally. What should I use in JQuery to get the result needed? (The first click on the element -> changes the state, the second click ANYWHERE -> brings the initial state back).

Comment: We need a much clearer example of what you tried, and what effects you're trying to create. All you've told us is what didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.element-1` is inside `body`, when you click on `.element-1` you are also clicking on `body`. The click event *propagates* from the target (`.element-1`) up to its parent, then the next parent, and so on. So the event on `.element-1` changes the state, then the event on `body` changes it back immediately. You can stop that happening with [`event.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
$(".element-1").mousedown(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
    // actions...
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped! However, I put mouseup after ".element-X" and set mousedown after "body". :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".element-1").click(function(){
   $(".element-1").animate(
     {
       width: //...;
       height: //...;
       //and other things you want
     },
     1000, //duration of the animation
     function () {
       $().hide("slow"); //to hide other contents
     }
   );
});
```

This should work for you and for to ***get back to the initial state*** you can simply animate again.